# MySQL REGEXP no funciona como debería

Tags: mysql, regex

Necesito hacer una consulta en una tabla usando REGEXP, pero por algún motivo algunas expresiones regulares que pruebo fallan y no entiendo por qué.

Hice un fiddle con el caso de prueba en http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e1dad3/5, igual coloco aquí los códigos por si acaso

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tabla` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Codigo` char(11) NOT NULL,
  `Nombre` char(37) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2528 ;    
--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `tabla`
--    
INSERT INTO `tabla` (`id`, `Codigo`, `Nombre`) VALUES
(23, 'C -III -013', 'Nombre'),
(55, 'C -I   -013', 'Nombre'),
(94, 'C -V   -013', 'Nombre'),
(98, 'C -IV  -013', 'Nombre'),
(279, 'C -II  -013', 'Nombre'),
(551, 'LA-I   -013', 'Nombre'),
(1215, 'C -VI  -013', 'Nombre'),
(1449, 'AP-I   -013', 'Nombre'),
(1506, 'AD-    -013', 'Nombre'),
(1536, 'C -VII -013', 'Nombre'),
(1722, 'LE-I   -013', 'Nombre'),
(1787, 'C -VIII-013', 'Nombre'),
(2021, 'C -IX  -013', 'Nombre'),
(2264, 'C -X   -013', 'Nombre'),
(2502, 'C -XI  -013', 'Nombre');

SELECT * FROM `tabla` WHERE Codigo REGEXP '\s*-013\s*$';
SELECT * FROM `tabla` WHERE Codigo REGEXP 'I\s*-013\s*$';
SELECT * FROM `tabla` WHERE Codigo REGEXP '-I\s*-013\s*$';
```

La primer consulta con la expresión regular `\s*-013\s*$` muestra todo correctamente, funciona bien

La segunda no, `I\s*-013\s*$` trae 1 solo resultado, `C -VIII-013` cuando en realidad los que tendrían que coincidir son todos estos:

```
C -III -013
C -I -013
C -II -013
LA-I -013
C -VI -013
AP-I -013
C -VII -013
C -VIII-013
C -XI -013
```

La tercera `-I\s*-013\s*$` directamente no trae nada, debería traer estos

```
C -I -013
LA-I -013
AP-I -013
LE-I -013
```

Estas expresiones las probé en https://regex101.com/ y allí funcionan bien. Por eso no entiendo por qué en MySQL no producen el resultado esperado.

Comment: en el segundo caso es como si solo funcionara cuando `\s*` tiene `\s` 0 veces, pues es la única ocurrencia en que `I` va seguido de `-013` sin ningún espacio entre ellos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que MySQL no soporta la notation `\s` en el REGEX, para solucionar el problema existe la notación `[[:space:]]` que es cualquier espacio en blanco. Esta notación existe para los espacios en blanco. Si hubiese algún otro caso, donde se nececite la diagonal invertida se debe utilizar la diagonal invertida doble (ej. `\&`, lo correcto sería `\\&`):

Por lo tanto un ejemplo de tu consulta seria:

```
SELECT * FROM `tabla` WHERE Codigo REGEXP '[[:space:]]*-013[[:space:]]*$';
SELECT * FROM `tabla` WHERE Codigo REGEXP 'I[[:space:]]*-013[[:space:]]*$';
SELECT * FROM `tabla` WHERE Codigo REGEXP '-I[[:space:]]*-013[[:space:]]*$';
```

Answer (score 3):

Mysql no reconoce el regex de espacio tal y como lo tienes puesto.

Tienes que poner **[[:space:]]** para el **/s**

Así que las regex te deberían quedar algo así

```
SELECT * FROM `tabla` WHERE Codigo REGEXP '[[:space:]]*-013[[:space:]]*$';
SELECT * FROM `tabla` WHERE Codigo REGEXP 'I[[:space:]]*-013[[:space:]]*$';
SELECT * FROM `tabla` WHERE Codigo REGEXP '-I[[:space:]]*-013[[:space:]]*$';
```

Te dejo la documentación oficial de mysql en cuanto a expresiones regulares

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html